# Wann starb der Plural auf "-s" im (Alt-)Deutschen aus oder wo kommt der Plural auf "-s" im Englischen her?

Tags: grammatical-number, english

Im Englischen werden die meisten Plurale mit der Endung *"-s"* gebildet (*"houses"*, *"cars"*) und nur die wenigsten auf die im Deutschen übliche Art mit *"-en"* (*"oxen"*, *"children"*).

Den Plural auf *"-s"* gibt es zwar auch im Deutschen bei Wörtern, die auf Vokale enden (*"Autos"*), aber nur bei neueren Wörtern. Ich nehme an, dass diese aus dem Englischen stammen.

Aber wie sah der Plural im Proto-Westgermanischen aus? Gab es beide Plurale auf *"-s"* und *"-en"* (und *"-e"* für andere Wörter) oder starb der *"-s"*-Plural auf dem Kontinent aus, bzw. ist der im Englischen übliche Plural auf *"-s"* romanischen Ursprungs (z.B. über Französisch oder Normannisch)?

Comment: "Autos" kommt nicht aus dem Englischen.

Comment: Es war für mich interessant zu beobachten wie meine kleinen Kinder instinktiv sehr oft den Plural jener Wörter mit -s gebildet haben, die Sing. und Plur. gleich lauten, z. B. *die Polsters* statt wie richtig: *die Polster*

Comment: Thei: woher kommt der Plural von "Auto" sonst? Haben Deutsche ganz spontan bechlossen, fuer die Kurzform von "Automobil" einen Plural zu benutzen, den es sonst im Deutschen einfach nicht gibt?

Comment: Splattne: Ja, aber wie kamen sie auf die Idee? Vielleicht gibt es einen versteckten Mechanismus im Deutschen, der impliziert, dass "-s" ein korrekter Plural ist, obwohl er (vor 1900) nie vorkommt.

Comment: @Andrew Bin mir nicht sicher, warum das so ist; ich empfehle zum Thema auf jeden Fall das hervorragende Buch von Stephen Pinker ["The Language Instinct"](http://www.amazon.com/Language-Instinct-Mind-Creates-P-S/dp/0061336467) ; auf Deutsch: ["Der Sprachinstinkt"](http://www.amazon.de/Sprachinstinkt-Wie-Geist-Sprache-bildet/dp/3426773635)

Comment: Haelst Du es fuer moeglich, dass es in der Sprache eine versteckte Regel gibt, die impliziert, dass ein Plural mit dem Genetiv (Singular) etwas zu tun hat? Das wuerde erklaeren, warum beide in vielen verwandten Sprachen auf "-s" enden und warum Kinder glauben, ein Plural auf "-s" waere in Ordnung. In manchen Sprachen (Russisch) wird ja auch bei manchen Zahlen der Genetiv statt Plural benutzt.

Comment: @Andrew J. Brehm: Einige behaupten, dass die Genetivform im Russischen eine alte Dualform wäre, die mit den Zahlen 2 bis 4 verwendet wird.

Comment: @Giorgio Das waere eine Erklaerung.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In der Dissertation für den Fachbereichs Germanistik und Kunstwissenschaften der Philipps-Universität Marburg mit dem Titel *"Die Entwicklung des deutschen Pluralsystems im 20. Jahrhundert"* ([PDF](http://archiv.ub.uni-marburg.de/diss/z2005/0525/pdf/dsaf.pdf)) erläutert der Autor im zweiten Kapitel die **historische Entwicklung des s-Plurals** im Deutschen:

> Die Diskussion  um den  s-Plural im Deutschen ist nicht neu in der deutschen 
>   Philologie, sondern reicht weit in die Vergangenheit zurück. Nach wie vor wird
>   der Status des s-Plurals kontrovers diskutiert.
>
> Einige Ansätze vertreten  die Hypothese, dass der s-Plural ursprünglich eine französische Form ist. Im Gegensatz dazu gehen andere Forscher davon aus, dass diese Form aus dem Niederdeutschen stammt. Die divergierenden Meinungen, die in der Literatur vertreten sind, können in vier Gruppen eingeteilt werden:
>
> I. Altsächsischer Ursprung
>   Hirt (1919) meint, dass der s-Plural direkt aus dem Altsächsischen stammt. Er
>   hat bei der Erklärung  der Formen wie Jungens bemerkt, dass der s-Plural die
>   einzige neuhochdeutsche Pluralendung ist, die auf das Indogermanische zurückgeht und die mit dem gotischen Plural auf –os identisch ist, z.B. Nominativ
>   Plural gotisch  Dago-s, dessen  -s sich  im Niederdeutschen  Jungens, Mäkens
>   erhalten hat. [...]
>
> II. Mittelniederdeutscher versus Mittelniederländischer Ursprung
>   Die zweite Gruppe meint, dass der neuhochdeutsche s-Plural über das Mittelniederdeutsche auf das Mittelniederländische zurückgeht, wobei sie über den
>   Ursprung  des mittelniederländischen  s-Plurals nicht einig  sind. Socin  äußerte
>   seine Meinung  dahingehend, dass der s-Plural in  der Schriftsprache aus dem
>   Niederdeutschen stammte. [...]
>
> III. Französischer Ursprung
>   Die dritte Gruppe vertritt eine Meinung, die besagt, dass der s-Plural direkt aus
>   dem Französischen stammt. Diese Meinung wird durch mehrere neuhochdeutsche Grammatiker vertreten. Matthias argumentiert, dass diese Pluralform ursprünglich in die Schriftsprache des 17. und 18. Jh.s durch viele eingedeutschte/dem Französisch  entlehnte, wie Bataillons, Mademoiselles etc. gekommen ist. [...]
>
> IV. Neubildung des Deutschen
>   Die vierte Gruppe geht davon aus, dass der s-Plural auf dem deutschen Sprachgebiet neu entstanden ist. Diese Meinung wurde von Behaghel schon früh vertreten. Er geht von den  ursprünglich  genitivischen  Pluralen  bei Eigennamen und Titelbezeichnungen aus wie: Meiers, Doktors, Scherers, Pfarrers, etc. Die Wörter wie Pfarrers und  Doktors sind  keine Pluralformen  von  Pfarrer und Doktor, sondern ist die Familie des Pfarrers, oder des Doktors, und sind somit aus dem Genitiv des Pfarrers entstanden, oder entstanden aus präpositionalen Verbindungen, wie ins Müllers (Haus). [...]

Die wissenschaftlichen Arbeit, deren Lektüre ich empfehle, da sie auch für Laien sehr aufschlussreich und interessant ist, enthält auch eine quantitative Analyse der Substantivendungen. Darin wird auch die Zunahme der Anzahl der s-Plural-Wörter im 20. Jh. deutlich.

Zusammenfassend kann man sagen, dass der s-Plural in der deutschen Sprache relativ neu ist. Die Forscher waren und sind sich nicht einig über die Herkunft dieser Pluralform.

---

Zur Frage, wie und wann das **Plural-s im Englischen** entstanden ist, gibt es auf der Seite *["History of English"](http://www.ielanguages.com/enghist.html)* folgende Erklärung:

> Middle English lost the case suffixes at the ends of nouns. Phonological erosion also occurred because of this, and some consonants dropped off while some vowels became əand dropped off too. The generalized plural marker became -s, but it still competed with -n.

Middle English (Mittelenglisch) ist die Form der englischen Sprache, die zwischen dem 12. und der Mitte des 15. Jahrhunderts gesprochen wurde. Wie im Zitat bereits erwähnt, weist Mittelenglisch gegenüber dem Altenglischen u. a. eine starke Vereinfachung der Flexionsformen auf; die übliche Pluralendung für fast alle Substantive wurde zu *-es* und -*en.*

Comment: Woher nimmst du immer nur deine verdammt gut recherchierten und erklärten Antworten? +1

Comment: Französisch... Darauf bin ich nicht gekommen. Das klingt für mich sehr wahrscheinlich! Kam es im Englischen vielleicht auch durch das Französische?

Answer (score 5):

I write this in English because I am not very confident with my German. I hope this is acceptable.

According to Braune (Abriß der althochdeutschen Grammatik), in old High-German the sound z of Proto-Germanic was changed to r inside a word and disappeared at the end of a word.
For example: Gothic maiza, Old High-German mero (Modern German mehr); Gothic sunus (Proto-Germanic sunuz), Old High-German sunu (Modern German Sohn).

So a final -z was turned into an -s by some languages of the family (e.g. English) and was dropped by Old High-German. Take the noun dag (day). The reconstructed Proto-Germanic plural is dagoz / dagos. English preserved the z giving days. German dropped the z, giving Tage. Swedish has dag, dagar (Swedish turned the final z into r, too).

So one popular plural ending is -s (from -z) in the languages that preserved it. High-German dropped the -z and has many plurals in -e.

The other popular ending is -en, which comes from the weak declension (nouns whose stems originally ended in -n).

After the original declension system of Proto-Germanic dissolved, each modern language built its own set of plural endings from what was left of the old declensions.

English has -s with some words still using -en, Umlaut (foot, feet), double ending -er + -en (children), etc. 
German uses -en, -e, -er, Umlaut, Umlaut combined with -e or -er, etc.
Dutch uses -en or -s, in a few cases -en with Umlaut (stad, steden), -er + -en (kinderen).

As splattne pointed out, the -s ending could have been adopted in Modern German from Dutch or from Low German Languages that still use it. On the other hand, if you want to know where the old Proto-Germanic -s (-z) ending went, look at the -e ending in words like Tage, Gäste, etc.